# REACT.JS > Want to get data from useMutation / onSuccess but Don't know How. useState does not work

Tags: reactjs

I am super newbie on programming.

I want to get data inside of useMutation / onSuccess method.

But It doesn't got what I wanted to.

I want to make my "item" to have data which is "data.id".

Is there any solution for this...?

```
import { Box, HStack, useToast, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useState } from "react";
import { FaCheckCircle } from "react-icons/fa";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { uploadQuestion } from "../api";
import { IQuestionDetail } from "../types";

export default function QuestionUploadWithPhoto() {
  const toast = useToast();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [item, setItem] = useState("");

  const uploadQustionMutation = useMutation(uploadQuestion, {
    onSuccess: (data: IQuestionDetail) => {
      // i want to get {data.id} and save it to a variable.
      // so I made an useState like above. and setItem like below.
      // BUT IT DOESN'T WORK !!!
      setItem(data.id);

      toast({
        position: "top",
        duration: 1500,
        render: () => (
          <Box rounded="lg" bg="rgba(255,105,0,1)" color="white" p={3}>
            <HStack>
              <FaCheckCircle />
              <Text>Success</Text>
            </HStack>
          </Box>
        ),
      });
      navigate(`/questions/${data.id}`);
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    uploadQustionMutation.mutate(data);
  };

...
...

  return (
...
... some code for form and button for submit...
...

... Want to print item below with data "data.id"...
<Text>{item}</Text>);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have invoked the mutation. You need to call the `uploadQustionMutation.mutate` somewhere in your code, maybe some button that does the `upload` operation. Refer here: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/mutations

Comment: Oh I forgot some code when I upload question! , I edited thank you @vighnesh153

Comment: You also `navigate` onSuccess. Because of that, your component might get unmounted and it won't be in view if the route is not the same.

Comment: @vighnesh153 Wow... Your answer saved my code!!!! How Can I say thank you more!! really really really really thank you!!!!